# Unable to resolve class org.ajoberstar.grgit.Grgit for GROOVY script

Tags: mule

I have tried to run the below code snippet but it returns the above exception

```
import org.ajoberstar.grgit.Grgit
import org.ajoberstar.grgit.Credentials

def grgit = Grgit.clone(dir: 'path/to/dir', url: 'git/uri/here')

grgit.close()
```

Any possible solutions?

Comment: Have you added the library to your classpath?

Comment: i am using it in mule through scripting module and dependencies were added to the pom file.

Comment: I have adjusted the tags.  Unless proven otherwise, this is not the fault of git or groovy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This flow works:

```
 <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <flow name="util-testFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/clone" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <scripting:component doc:name="Groovy">
            <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[import org.ajoberstar.grgit.Grgit
import org.ajoberstar.grgit.Credentials

def grgit = Grgit.clone(dir: 'test', uri: 'https://github.com/rmccue/test-repository.git')

grgit.close()]]></scripting:script>
        </scripting:component>
    </flow>
```

As long as you have the following in your pom.xml:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ajoberstar/grgit -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.ajoberstar</groupId>
  <artifactId>grgit</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```